# How to do RSA encryption for IOS using Ionic

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, public-key-encryption

I'm developing a native android app and hybrid IOS app. I'm encrypting the password before sending the request to BL. Below is my native code.

```
public String Encrypt (String plain) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
{
    try {
        AssetManager assets = context.getAssets();
        byte[] key = readFully(
                assets.open("encryption.der", AssetManager.ACCESS_BUFFER));
        KeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(key);

        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        Key pk = kf.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        CipherOutputStream cout = new CipherOutputStream(out, cipher);
        try {
            cout.write(plain.getBytes(UTF_8));
            cout.flush();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                cout.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        encrypted  = new String(encode(out.toByteArray(), DEFAULT), "UTF-8");

        return encrypted;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}

static byte[] readFully(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        int readLen, size = 0;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while ((readLen = in.read(tmp)) != -1) {
            if (((long) size + readLen) > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                // woah! did we just ship an app of 2GB?
                throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid file. File size exceeds expected "
                        + "maximum of 2GB");
            }
            size += readLen;
            out.write(tmp, 0, readLen);
        }
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
```

I have my key in encryption.der file. Everything works fine in android. Now coming to IOS which I'm using Ionic to develop. I'm not able to achieve the encryption part. I have used the "cryptico" : link : https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico/blob/master/README.md . 
And finally converting to Base64 like these.

```
var EncryptionPassword = cryptico.encrypt($scope.userInfo.Password, publicKey);
$scope.encPass = base64.encode(EncryptionPassword.cipher);
```

But I'm getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception from BL. Can you suggest exact same solution has android for angularjs too. So RSA encrytion works on both IOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Service and place your public Key inside that.

   .service('Settings', function(){

   this.publicKey = 'MIIBIjANBgdcssvsvsfvsfvsfvrefvfvfviuwoihijwfoiw278499080989i09M+KC8MYYOu/NRLmFg85LRrfRszyI/vZ/k8982789uiwbgchdbhU+3joQZoJ3Sxq/GbIIFf/3y4f9DuKI53y1qR2qD4xIskfa9rPVqvBtAu2KSNRd8V4J8RKI2gT2YEA+A3Z0mQq4GBRS8iYmGLqRQyPfNUSankylBrTpOIVFBZORdZehjJMmwl98UynyfnyMIHUIFuhefuibiufbeufbsoijn93fD7nxt+siZryfazn3EAgBaTKTV/U5xIepzDN6ZYJ4qnC93u6erdb1X4m1zU6RGapwzCOPOORTyzw/uWJ8twcODNt0cqVp+sYQIDAQAB';
   })

   2. Now in your JS encrypt using public key and JSEncrypt.

   var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();                                                  encrypt.setPublicKey(Settings.publicKey);
   EncryptionPin = encrypt.encrypt($scope.customerInfo.Pin);

EncryptionPin is the final key.